# How to chain promises

Tags: javascript, promise

In this simplified example, I am calling three functions when the first promise gets resolved.

```
var test = new Promise(function (res, err) { setTimeout(res, 3000) })

test.then( () => { console.log("A") });
test.then( () => { 
    return new Promise(function(res, err) { 
        setTimeout(()=> { console.log("C"); 
        res() }, 3000) 
    }); 
});

test.then( () => { console.log("B") });
```

The output as expected is `A B C`.

Let's suppose that I want to invoke the third `.then` to console `B` only when the second promise gets resolved.

If I try to store the second promise (`myProm`) in global and attach a `.then` function on it, I'll get (reasonably) a TypeError because at compile time myProm is still undefined.

```
var test = new Promise(function (res, err) { setTimeout(res, 3000) })
var myProm;

test.then( () => { console.log("A") });
test.then( () => { 
    myProm = new Promise(function(res, err) { 
        setTimeout(()=> { console.log("C"); 
        res() }, 3000) 
    })
    return myProm;
});

myProm.then( () => { console.log("B") });
```

How do I proceed? What's the best way to chain two promises together so that the returned Promise obj from one `.then` needs to get resolved before we can execute the next `then`.

In this scenario, the output I'd like to have would be `A C B`

Comment: `test.then(...).then(...)`…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `.then`, you create a *new* `Promise` that resolves when the `Promise` returned by that `.then` resolves. You should assign the result of the `myProm`-containing `.then` to a variable, and then call `.then` on that variable:

```js
var test = new Promise(function (res, err) { setTimeout(res, 500) })
var myProm;

test.then( () => { console.log("A") })
  .then( () => { 
      myProm = new Promise(function(res, err) { 
          setTimeout(()=> { console.log("C"); 
          res() }, 500) 
      })
      return myProm;
  })
  .then( () => { console.log("B") });
```

*Most of the time* when using `Promises`, you should be chaining `.then`s like this. Only do `prom.then(...) ... prom.then(...)` when you want to initialize two *completely separate* asynchronous operations when the `prom` resolves.

Comment: > Each time you call .then, you create a new Promise that resolves when the Promise returned by that .then resolves. 

is it an implicit promise? can you point the spec?

Comment: It's a full-fledged `Promise`, not really implicit at all. See [MDN's notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) on chaining

Answer (score 2):

`then` returns a promise that resolves when the indicated function has run and the value it returned has resolved (this is a slight oversimplification, but sufficient for the task here).

Therefore, to chain a promise on the result of a `then`. Just tack on another `.then`:

```js
var test = new Promise(function (res, err) { setTimeout(res, 3000) })

test.then( () => { console.log("A") });
test
    .then( () => { 
        return new Promise(function(res, err) { 
            setTimeout(()=> { console.log("C"); res() }, 3000);
        });
    })
    .then( () => { console.log("B") });
```

Comment: …and don't forget the `return` keyword in the `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi what happens if you miss a return statement, does it implicitly return undefined?

Comment: @leonardofed Yes, but then it won't wait for the promise you created in the callback but just for `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi okay, this means that the promise will be resolved immediately as undefined and it will break the asynchronicity of my code. Correct?

Comment: @leonardofed Yes, if you removed the `return` from line 6 of my code above, then `B` would be logged before `C`, for example.